# Send form fields in html email

Tags: php, mysql

I have an HTML user form. User will fill form from webpage, when user submit that form then it will go to admin email(including form fields i.e textfield, checkbox etc) as originally filled by user

Now the problem is that form send to gmail, yahoo, hotmail as i want but to outlook it is sent as see in pic below,

[image]

I'm using this code below,

```
$headers = "From: " ."mail@example.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". "mail@example.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = "<html><body><table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input type='text' value='test user' name='name'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Education</td>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' name='graduate' value='graduate' checked='checked' />Graduate<br/>
            <input type='checkbox' name='high_school' value='high_school'/>High School<br/>
            <input type='checkbox' name='primary_school' value='primary_school'/>Primary School<br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table></body></html>";
```

Note : User will fill the form from webpage, the out put will go to admin email same as in the original form.

Comment: not surprised an email client may strip form fields since you cant submit a form from a sent email (well not in most desktop clients). where you expecting people to fill that in- in their email client?

Comment: @Dagon: Working since Netscape 3? - However I would not expect it to work in *every* email-client, too. Some mail-filters might even strip things dues to security reasons.

Comment: depends on the client. support is bad for most desktop ones, web mail clients are ok.

Comment: Your form may be unworkable in many mail clients, not only Outlook. It's much better to send user to web-page with form in browser.

Comment: @Dagon the picture shown above is the out put of a form in my inbox, check the pic, i update it .

Comment: yes. well and? not usable on outlook - send a link to a web page instead.

Comment: @Dagon sorry i think i didnt explain my question well, user will fill form from webpage, when user submit that form then it will go to admin email as original filled form by user

Comment: accept the limitation of the medium, email clients are not web browsers, their html support is not the same. Just send the results as regular text.

Comment: Stay one step ahead of those wily *exchanginistas* in Outlook and do them one better: Make it a PDF or non-form HTML view. I don't know anybody who would know what to do with an HTML form they got in email. They usually come ask me, what do we do with this?

Comment: The OP wants to show *the results as an E-Mail* containing the form elements. They're not part of an active form. (The answer that he probably should find another way to do this still stands, though.)

Comment: I tried adding <form> tags in case that was why Outlook wasn't rendering the form elements, but it still didn't work.  FYI, it works fine in Outlook Express (Windows Live Mail) even without form tags.  I would do what others suggested and use images instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to work around this restriction, it's likely to be there for security reasons. Also, using actual form fields may be very confusing - when seeing them, users might expect some opportunity for interaction where there is none.

Have you considered using a graphical symbol instead?

- It would work in all clients
- It would be independent from how the user's OS renders checkboxes

Answer (score 3):

You could use images instead of the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Post a link to a web site which serves the form. When the user fills in the form, post the results from the form to the admin / staff.

HTML plus Forms plus Email = nightmare.

Many people (like me) only look at "plain text" emails for a start, which means no HTML and no images at all.